# Javascript code wont work in IE

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a database populated dropdown table that is not working in IE when I try to use

```
<script>
$(".viewall").click(function () {


    $(".alltable").css("display", "table");
    $(".alltable tr").css("display", "table-row");  
    $(".alltable td").css("display", "table-cell");
        });
$(".closeall").click(function () {


    $(".alltable").css("display", "none");
    $(".alltable tr").css("display", "none");
    $(".alltable td").css("display", "none");

});

</script>
```

I use to use slideDown() in JQuery and work but took way to long.....if you could give me a hand thanks :)

Comment: did u include jQuery reference?? before this script?

Comment: What version of IE, you know there is a bunch and they all act differently?

Comment: Yes at top I included it in my header switch I created the file and stored in system so it wouldnt bug https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not make sense, why are you hiding it on 3 different levels? If you hide the outer level, they will all be hidden! Also you are reinventing jQuery's hide() and show().

```
$(".viewall").click(function () {
    $(".alltable").show();
});
$(".closeall").click(function () {
    $(".alltable").hide();
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect thanks and I did not know there was a .show or .hide() :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set a short animation speed for slideDown()?

Comment: Haha you sure can! I think it's the first parameter. http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/